# Get Custom Labels via API

Tags: customlabel, heroku, node-salesforce, nforce

What is the easiest way to get a custom label from outside the platform (eg: node js or other app)?

I'm using [nforce](https://www.npmjs.org/package/nforce), but surprisingly don't see any api methods to get custom labels.

Answer (score 5):

A quick glance at the nforce source makes it appear to not have support for fetching custom labels.

I can't see a way to fetch custom labels via the REST API either, nor can I find any references to custom labels in the SOAP API. Based on that I don't believe labels are readily useable off-platform without something like a custom apex REST/SOAP service (although there are complications as you can't fetch labels dynamically in apex) or by processing the CustomLabels.labels XML file from the metadata API.

However I have to ask you to clarify, do you mean the custom labels defined in the Setup > Create > Custom Labels menu, or the user friendly text for things like SObject fields?

Comment: Yes I'm talking about the Setup>Create>Custom Labels

Answer (score 5):

I can't believe they still haven't added this to the rest API.  You can now access classes and tons of other meta-data but still no custom labels.

I've written a custom REST resource to allow this (as [sfdcfox suggested](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41042/access-custom-labels-from-native-ios-app)).  It uses the VF page `getContent()` hack which can be explained in more [detail here](https://kksfblog.wordpress.com/2015/03/27/lost-in-translation-an-api-for-dynamically-translating-custom-labels-in-apex/).

**VisualForce Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="DynamicCustomLabel" contentType="application/json" showHeader="false" sidebar="false"
    language="{!lang}" standardStylesheets="false">{!$Label[name]}</apex:page>
```

**Page Controller:**

```
public class DynamicCustomLabel {
    public String lang {get;set;}
    public String name {get;set;}

    public  DynamicCustomLabel(){
       Map<String, String> reqParams = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
       lang = reqParams.get('lang');
       name = reqParams.get('name');
    }
}
```

**Rest Resource:**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/customlabel')
global with sharing class DynamicCustomLabelResource  {

    @HttpGet
    global static String getLabel() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        String name = req.params.get('name');
        String lang = req.params.get('lang');
        try{
            return getLabel(name, lang);
        }catch(Exception e){
            RestContext.response.statusCode = 404;
            return '';
        }
    }

    public static  String getLabel(String labelName, String language){
        Pagereference r = Page.DynamicCustomLabel;
        r.getParameters().put('lang', language);
        r.getParameters().put('name', labelName);
        String labelValue = r.getContent().toString();
        return labelValue;
    }
}
```

Calling it:

`[HOST]/services/apexrest/customlabel?name=MyCustomLabel`
`[HOST]/services/apexrest/customlabel?name=MyCustomLabel&lang=EN`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Salesforce tooling API to do that. Here is the code example using Python and simple-salesforce lib https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce


def connect() -> Salesforce:
    login = "some.email@gmail.com"
    password = "sf_pass"
    token = "sf_token"  # https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.user_security_token.htm&type=5

    return Salesforce(username=login, password=password, security_token=token)


def print_labels(sf: Salesforce):
    q = """
        select id, name, value
        from CustomLabel
    """

    res = sf.restful('tooling/query/', params={'q': q})

    for r in res["records"]:
        print(r["Name"] + " = " + r["Value"])


con = connect()
print_labels(con)
```